# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy : Spring API and Angular UI

Tags: angular, spring, cors

I am trying to access a REST API running on my tomcat server at localhost:9090 from my angular UI application hosted in node server at localhost:4200.

This is the error I am getting and not able to access the service

The default error seen in browser console

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9090/rest/authentication/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

After adding the CORS plugin in Chrome and turning off the CORS in browser, this is the error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9090/rest/authentication/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:4200, *', but only one is allowed.

The REST service is build using Spring 5.0 and we tried handling the cross origin by adding the following in web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
             <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
                    <param-value>http://localhost:4200</param-value>
             </init-param>
             <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
                    <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
             </init-param>
             <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
                    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Authorization,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
             </init-param>
             <init-param>
                    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
                    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
             </init-param>
       </filter>

</filter>
```

Any solution to overcome this CORS error

Answer (score 1):

Add a `@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")` annotation to your controller or its method or enable CORS globally:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // Don't do this in production, use a proper list  of allowed origins
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

**edit**

In case it's a Spring Security issue, add this to your SecurityConfig:

```
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token", "xsrf-token", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: We tried the @crossOrigin at controller level. But that did not work, as the error is getting thrown even before reaching the Controller Class. Can you please detail on how to enable CORS globally. Is it by adding a custom filter class which extends  javax.servlet.Filter and add the logic as shown in your comments.

Comment: The application is not Spring Boot, it is normal Spring framework. Also we have a custom filter class implementation where we validate the logged in user. The request that we receive in this layer is of type Options and not the actual GET/POST request fired from the UI.

Comment: @chinnuNish The only reason I can think of is Spring Security blocking it (notice that you DO add the Options method to the filter). I've added an edit